# Print disclaimer when loading package

Tags: r, package

I would like to print a disclaimer/warning when a package I created is being loaded. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: You can use a `.onAttach` function for this and print a message or warning for uses when it is called

Comment: you can look at how other packages implement this suggestino; see [GA](https://github.com/luca-scr/GA/blob/c5068688888b112f0c336a54046868142d9ce90d/R/zzz.R), [ggplot2](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/d6d847956f52aa7732c4cf78c9dae248ce8bf41c/R/zzz.r), [data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/fc2779995f92ff74eca37873d5eb151558c2c0e4/R/onAttach.R) etc